# Avoid unnecessary fields at group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

1. **Campaign**

| id | budget |
| --- | --- |
| 345 | 1650 |
| 346 | 2320 |

2. **Report**

| campaign_id | ad_id | cost | deals | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | 1 | 45 | 2 | 2022-01-01 |
| 345 | 2 | 20 | 10 | 2022-01-01 |
| 345 | 1 | 70 | 0 | 2022-01-02 |
| 346 | 1 | 100 | 3 | 2022-01-01 |
| 346 | 2 | 250 | 6 | 2022-01-01 |

**3. Reach**

| campaign_id | reach | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | 110 | 2022-01-01 |
| 346 | 90 | 2022-01-01 |

I want to JOIN field `budget` from table #1 to table #2 and JOIN field `reach` from table #1 to table #1, and GROUP it by campaign_id and date. So I need to SUM(cost) and SUM(deals), but what about budget and reach from another tables? I can't aggregate them, but also I don't want to add these fields to GROUP BY because logically it's not correct I guess.

So how can I join these tables and avoid unnecessary fields at GROUP BY statement?

Result should be:

| campaign_id | cost | deals | date | budget | reach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | 65 | 12 | 2022-01-01 | 1650 | 110 |
| 345 | 70 | 0 | 2022-02-01 | 1650 | NULL |
| 346 | 350 | 9 | 2022-01-01 | 2320 | 90 |

Comment: On option is using a derived table to join t2 + t3 and aggregate. Then join the result back to t1.  `SELECT ... FROM t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT ... FROM t2 JOIN t3 ON ... ) totals ON totals.campaign_id = t1.id`

Comment: "I can't aggregate them": why not?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use **`LEFT JOIN`** while joining **`Reach`** table to the others along with matching **`campaign_id`** and **`date`** columns while including **`reach`** column within the `GROUP BY` list such as

```
SELECT r.campaign_id, 
       SUM(cost) AS cost, SUM(deals) AS deals, r.date, MAX(budget) AS budget, reach
  FROM Campaign AS c
  JOIN Report AS r
    ON c.id = r.campaign_id
  LEFT JOIN Reach AS re
    ON c.id = re.campaign_id
   AND re.date = r.date 
 GROUP BY r.campaign_id, r.date, reach 
 ORDER BY r.campaign_id, r.date
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e7e673f18384d0f6d2deca08a0e01a64)</kbd>